# Dynamic segment with Google analytics API V3 return 400 error

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use dynamic segments in a google analytics api v3 with this library :

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

I try to define a segment with this :

```
dynamic::ga:medium==organic;
```

But it return me a 400 error.

Previously I was using this library :

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

with the same request and it worked fine.

Anyone know why it doesn't work anymore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the new API doesn't accept last ; in dynamics segments.

So instead of :

```
dynamic::ga:medium==organic;
```

Write :

```
dynamic::ga:medium==organic
```